# Docker does not work behind proxy

Tags: docker, proxy

unfortunately, I can't use my docker behind the proxy , I do what googling search suggest and this is the error I get when I run `sudo docker run hello-world`:

```
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-
1.docker.io/v2/: Proxy Authentication Required.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

this is my '/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf' file :

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:8800/"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=https://user:pass@127.0.0.1:8800/"
```

my "etc/default/docker" file :

```
export http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:3128/"
export https_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:3128/"
export HTTP_PROXY="http://127.0.0.1:3128/"
export HTTPS_PROXY="http://127.0.0.1:3128/"
```

what is the problem?
thank you :)

Comment: Tell your docker version and which OS?

Comment: After adding the proxy did you do `daemon reload` and docker `restart` ?

Comment: @Shettyh yes I did.

Comment: @Saran Ubuntu 17.04 , Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this,

```
$ sudo vim /etc/resolv.conf

#add these lines on top and above one for home router…
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

After saving the `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

run `$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload` for reloading daemon process.

Then restart your docker :

run `$ sudo systemctl restart docker`

Comment: sorry, but where can I find docker log?

Comment: @mahshidkhatami I update my answer. See these steps if you did already?

Answer (score 0):

Docker is not available is some countries because of some unfair sanctions by US which are targeting people directly also startups ...

Any way you can use registry docker instead of docker_hub.
But for creating images and container from micro-services and projects and run them (local) you check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56883068/6033946)

All the best :)