# Why the container does not start after starting it in CMD ( docker )?

Tags: docker, .net-core

First I create an image of project then create container then I want to start it 
but after starting the container it exits 
. why it says " Exited (145) 2 seconds ago " for started container?
check the image

[image: exited]

I did what @Jamie said
this is the result :

```
PM> docker run myimage -d
docker : Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK 
from:
At line:1 char:1
+ docker run myimage -d
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Did you mean to...otnet SDK 
from::String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

 https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
```

DockerFile :

[image]

I am using this tutorial :
[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/build-container)

I did what @Pierre said . this is the result 
(No change)
[image]

Comment: If you were to run the image with the `docker run myimage -d` (i.e. without detaching) rather than using the `docker start` command, you'll see any text which is output to the console within the container. This will give you clues as to why the container stopped.

Comment: check the question please i modified it . @JamieTaylor

Comment: I am using this tutorial to host a .net core project in docker:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/build-container

Comment: Can you show your Dockerfile?

Comment: From the output, it looks like you are using a runtime image, but calling an SDK command. as @PierreB. said, could you share your dockerfile?

Comment: this is my docker file @JamieTaylor :
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:2.2

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app/app4.dll"]

Comment: Add it to the question by editing ;)

Comment: sure I am doing it ..

Comment: In your screen shot, Visual Studio is showing that you are building in debug mode (the select next to the run button [looks like a green play button]) have you performed a publish of your app in Release mode? The docker file you are referencing copies files from the default output path from a publish in Release mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was related to my docker file :

I created another project 
I followed this tutorial :[tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/)

I used the docker file in mentioned link and modified it a little bit based on my project needs.

```
  FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-1709 AS base
  WORKDIR /app
  EXPOSE 80
  EXPOSE 443

  FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk-nanoserver-1709 AS build
  WORKDIR /src
  COPY ./wa2.csproj ./
  RUN dotnet restore
  COPY . .
  WORKDIR /src
  RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

  FROM build AS publish
  RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

  FROM base AS final
  WORKDIR /app
  COPY --from=publish /app .
  ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "wa2.dll"]
```

Then I created image from project

```
  $ docker build -t myimage2 -f Dockerfile .
```

(I had to switch to windows container from docker as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43346580/docker-image-operating-system-windows-cannot-be-used-on-this-platform)

I faced a weird error which will be solved by help of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47837720/6033946) 
(By the way, VPN was also Off)

The mentioned error on building image. This is the error line "RUN dotnet restor"

[image: here]

then I executed these two line on command in project folder

// create container

```
 $ docker build -t (project name) .
```

// run container

```
 $ docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name (container name) (project name)
```

the container is created and I could run it. then I could see the result from 2 port one from Visual studio another from Docker

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the part where you need to copy the files into Docker image as shown in [the tutorial you are following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/build-container#create-the-dockerfile) before `ENTRYPOINT`:

```
COPY app/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/publish/ app/
```

Comment: I added the result to the question please check it @Pierre

Comment: Are the logs showing the same issue? (by the way it would be easier if you added text instead of images)

Comment: I am not getting what the "log" is . where is it ? @Pierre

Comment: use `docker logs` - you seemed to be quite new to Docker, maybe you should take a look at the official site and the getting started guide ;) https://docs.docker.com/get-started/